# Frame time stamps are either out of order or repeating

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

When returning from one view controller to a view controller with the ARKit I get `VIO error callback: 49540.263312, 3, Frame time stamps are either out of order or repeating`

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
   // Pause the view's session
   sceneView.session.pause()
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
   configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
   let options: ARSession.RunOptions = [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors]        
   sceneView.debugOptions = [.showFeaturePoints]
   sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: options)
}
```

How can I synchronise the frames?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: not yet. @BlackRock do you have the same problem or any idea?

Comment: In my project I use two different viewcontrollers with ARKit, when I returned to the first view controller this error occurred to me. I solved the problem by completely reloading the first viewcontroller, inserting both of them in a container view to better manage them.

Comment: May you show me a code snippet as example?

Comment: @BlackRock do you also have problems getting the world orientation back after switching between the AR-ViewControllers? On iOS13 I get the message  "Can not get world orientation cause if high memory ..."

Comment: There is no code snippet, the code depending by your project structure, just insert the two viewcontrollers in a container view as child. If you have memory issue container view may be help you.